# Link not working inside of <li>

Tags: html, anchor

I looked at the answers to similar questions, but none provided the help I need; I'm still getting unresponsive links !?
To be clearer, by unresponsive links I mean the link does not work; they style exactly as expected.

Here's the CSS:

```
#nav3 { padding: 0; margin:15px 15px 0; height:29px; background-repeat: repeat; background-position: left top; }
.ddcolortabs { padding: 0; width: 100%; }
.ddcolortabs ul { font: normal 13px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0 0 0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
.ddcolortabs li { display:inline; margin:0 2px 0 0; padding:0; }
.ddcolortabs a { float:left; color: #4963AE; background: #B9D6E5 url(../../content/themes/wd/images/tabs/color_tabs_left.png) no-repeat left top; margin:0 6px 0 0; padding:0 0 1px 3px; text-decoration:none; letter-spacing: 1px; font-weight: bold; }
.ddcolortabs a.selected { background: #98a5d3 url(../../content/themes/wd/images/tabs/color_tabs_left.png) no-repeat left top; color: #FFF; }
.ddcolortabs a span { float:left; display:block; padding: 8px 20px 6px 19px; background: transparent url(../../content/themes/wd/images/tabs/color_tabs_right.png) no-repeat right top; }
```

And here's the html:

```
<div id="nav3">
    <div id="colortab2" class="ddcolortabs">
        <ul style="margin-left:10px;">
            <li><a href="../MostActive"><span>Most Active</span></a> </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected"><span>Most Popular</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../MostRecent"><span>Most Recent</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../BrowseCategories"><span>Browse Categories</span></a></li>       
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How exactly are they not working?  Clicking them doesn't work or they aren't styling the way you want them to?

Comment: What do you mean by unresponsive? That markup works for me.

Comment: Any chance there is an invisible element elsewhere in your markup that is blocking the click event?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript that might intercept clicks on `<li>` elements?

Comment: mrtsherman > no invisible element

Comment: kijin > no javascript running on the page at all

Comment: Is this specific to just one particular browser version or have you tried multiple with the same results?  This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qczj/) seems to show that it does work (at least in Safari 5.1.5 on OS X Lion).

Answer (score 1):

My bad, higher in the markup I had a div styled with z-index: -1

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue.  I solved it by including the full link for the page plus the anchor.

`<a href="/PAGENAME#anchor-link">Click here</a>`

Annoying issue to have.  It was working fine locally prior to making this change.  I am not sure if the web host's server plays a part in this somehow?