# AngularJS prevents HTML5 download link from starting a download

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to create a hyperlink that on click starts download of a file (usually shown in the bottom-left corner of browser).

I use HTML5 mode with disabled rewrites:

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, rewriteLinks: false});
}
```

And here's my link with HTML5 download attribute:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="download-formats">
    <li><a href="/api/v1/rna/{{ rna.upi }}.fasta" download="{{ rna.upi }}.fasta">FASTA</a></li>
</ul>
```

Somehow, clicking on this link doesn't have any effect at all (I'm using latest Chrome). Is it supposed to be that way?

**ANSWER:** so the issues was that this markup with download link was contained in another element with click event handler checking, if `href` attribute is not populated (as is the case for href, using angularjs interpolated content). If it wasn't populated, it called `preventDefault()`, so I was unable to get the html5 download action to run. I had to do an imperative implementation of download in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-href` instead of `href`

```
<li><a ng-href="/api/v1/rna/{{ rna.upi }}.fasta" download="{{ rna.upi }}.fasta">FASTA</a></li>
```

Comment: I did. =) Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: in the browser console check the href url is binded

Comment: Yes, it correctly resolves to `/api/v1/rna/URS00000F78F0.fasta`. If I open `localhost:8000/api/v1/rna/URS00000F78F0.fasta`, it shows me the file.

Comment: maybe you need to add the domain to the url also

Comment: Interesting enough, even if I prepend `http://localhost:8000` to the url, it still won't start the download, although this is a full download path! I copy-pasted it to another tab and this link contains the file. Tried both with `href` and with `ng-href`.

Comment: is it working if you put it outside `li` and `ul` tags

Comment: Aha, yes, it does! Thank you, Sachila. So, those are probably some smartass bootstrap directives blocking the default behaviour or propagation of click event.

Comment: i think so. maybe you can resolve this by adding some custom style. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961572/link-not-working-inside-of-li

Comment: Its actually located within a ui-bootstrap tab header, so there are `<uib-tab><uib-tab-heading></uib-tab-heading></uib-tab>` surrounding this dropdown list. My gut feeling is that they are preventing the default action somehow: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js.

Comment: Just reloads the angularJS app.